# What is the eigenvalue of Coulomb potential $V(\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2)=\dfrac{e^2}{\left|\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2\right|}$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrostatics, hilbert-space, potential-energy, coulombs-law

Assume that there is a comlomb potential between 2 electrons $V(\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2)=\dfrac{e^2}{\left|\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2\right|}$. In quantum mechanics, $V\to\hat{V}$, so $V$ will be $ V(
\hat{\vec{r}}_1-\hat{\vec{r}}_2)=\dfrac{e^2}{\left|\hat{\vec{r}}_1-\hat{\vec{r}}_2\right|}$. What's the eigenvalue of $\dfrac{e^2}{\left|\hat{\vec{r}}_1-\hat{\vec{r}}_2\right|}\left|\vec{r}_1\right>$ or $\dfrac{e^2}{\left|\hat{\vec{r}}_1-\hat{\vec{r}}_2\right|}\left|\vec{r}_2\right>$?

And how to calculate this integral?

\begin{equation}
\left<2\right|\left<1\right|\hat{V}\left|1\right>\left|2\right>=?
\end{equation}
By the way, $\left<\boldsymbol{r}_i|i\right>=\phi_{i}(\boldsymbol{r}_i)$

Comment: There will be no associates eigenvalue to those states, because the states aren't eigenstates of the operator, they are not even in the Hilbert space the operator acts on. (Being single particle states, while the operator is a two-particle operator).

Comment: So how to calculate this integral ?$\left<1\right|\left<2\right|\hat{V}\left|2\right>\left|1\right>$

Comment: $\left| r_1 \right> \otimes \left| r_2 \right>$ *is* an eigenvector of the operator. And here you can just use the usual rules of operator calculus, for an eigenstate $f(A) \left|\psi\right> = f(\lambda) \left|\psi\right>$. Here it helps to keep in mind that $\hat{r}_1$ is actually $\hat{r}_1 \otimes \mathbb{1}$ and $\hat{r}_2$ is actually $\mathbb{1} \otimes \hat{r}_2$. There is a further minor complicaiton: electrons cant be prepared in that state, it needs to be antisymmetrized (but this is irrelevant for the calculation).

Comment: So $\hat{V}\left|\vec{r}_1,{r}_2\right>={e^2\over r_{12}}\left|\vec{r}_1,{r}_2\right>$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @SebastianRiese An eigenvalue should be a constant. It cannot be a function of electron-electron distance. Your comment, which should have been an answer, is not correct.

Comment: My answer was deleted as it was judged to be 'not answering the question' by @Chris. I disagree. It is useless but the correct answer to the question in the title.

Comment: @my2cts The eigenvalue depends on the state, but is just a number for a given state – note that both $r_1$ and $r_2$ are fixed by the state. The eigenvalue of course depends on the state, so do the eigenvalues of e.g. the harmonic oscillator Hamiltonian. (Of course there are subtleties insofar position eigenstates are not in the Hilbert space.) My comment is close to, a full answer, but still just a hint that helped Michael to figure it out themself which I consider the best possible outcome.

Comment: @SebastianRiese Do you interpret $|r_1\rangle$ as $\delta({\bf r} - {\bf r}_1)$ ? That would imply an infinite kinetic energy. If that is what intended then your comment/answer is correct. I guess.

Comment: Yes, $\left< r \middle| r_1 \right> = \delta(r - r_1)$ and to my knowledge this is standard notation. Also the question clarifies the notation in the last paragraph (although this was edited in later). Also, we don't care about kinetic energy here, because we consider the eigenvalues and eigentstates of the operator $\hat V$ isolated. (Sorry for being sloppy with marking the vectors as such, it's a bad habit)

Comment: You appear to be asking for the *expectation value* of $V$, not the eigenvalue of $V$.

Comment: @SebastianRiese "we don't care about kinetic energy here" Nor about wave equations, uncertainty, in short, quantum mechanics. This is not mainstream physics.

Comment: @my2cts Yes it is, because the question is technical, about how to compute a certain term that may well occur in a reasonable main-stream physics calculation. You can use non-physical states to compute physical results (as you always do when working the in momentum or position bases). That does not make questions about the technical aspects non-mainstream physics.

Comment: @SebastianRiese If you don't care about kinetic energy and solve the equation $H\psi=V\psi$ you are **very far away from making sense**. However there is a solution. I give it in my - deleted- answer.

Comment: @my2cts This question is not about solving the time-independent Schrödinger equation! This question is specifically about the eigenvalue (not the eigenenergy! the operator in question is *not* the full Hamiltonian!) of a certain operator for a certain state. It may well be that the poster wanted to know something different (in a kind of X-Y-problem); but the question as stated can still be answered.

Comment: why do you care about eigenvalues of $\hat V(\vec r_1-\vec r_2)$?  What is the physical significances without $\hat p_1^2/2m_e$ and $\hat p_2^2/2m_e$ added into the mix?

Answer (score 1):

The Hilbert space that the operator $V$ acts on requires you to specify a position state for both particles. In other words, a position eigenstate is not $|\vec{r}_1\rangle$, it is $|\vec{r}_1\rangle | \vec{r}_2\rangle$, meaning that in this state the first particle is at position $\vec{r}_1$ and the second particle is at position $\vec{r}_2$

The state $|\vec{r}_1\rangle | \vec{r}_2\rangle$ is an eigenstate of the operator $\hat{V}$ with eigenvalue $e^2 |\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2|^{-1}$, like so

\begin{equation}
\hat{V} |\vec{r}_1\rangle | \vec{r}_2\rangle 
= \frac{e^2}{|\hat{\vec{r}}_1 - \hat{\vec{r}}_2|} |\vec{r}_1\rangle | \vec{r}_2\rangle 
=\frac{e^2}{| \vec{r}_1 - \vec{r}_2|} |\vec{r}_1\rangle | \vec{r}_2\rangle 
\end{equation}

To compute the integral, try inserting a complete set of states twice and using the above, like so

\begin{eqnarray}
\langle 1 | \langle 2 | \hat{V} | 2 \rangle | 1 \rangle &=& \int d \vec{r}_1 d \vec{r}_2 d \vec{r}'_1 d \vec{r}'_2 \langle 1 |  \vec{r}_1 \rangle \langle 2 | \vec{r}_2 \rangle \langle \vec{r}_1 | \langle \vec{r}_2 | \hat{V} | \vec{r}'_2 \rangle | \vec{r}'_1 \rangle \langle \vec{r}'_2 | 2 \rangle \langle \vec{r}'_1 | 1 \rangle \\
&=& \int d \vec{r}_1 d \vec{r}_2 d \vec{r}'_1 d \vec{r}'_2 \phi_1^\star (\vec{r}_1) \phi_2^\star (\vec{r}_2) \frac{e^2}{|\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2|} \phi_1(\vec{r}'_1) \phi_2(\vec{r}'_2) \delta (\vec{r}_1 - \vec{r}'_1) \delta(\vec{r}_2 - \vec{r}'_2) \\
&= & e^2 \int d \vec{r}_1 d \vec{r}_2 \frac{|\phi_1(\vec{r}_1)|^2 |\phi_2(\vec{r}_2)|^2 }{|\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2|}
\end{eqnarray}